# Python remove punctuation from a text file

Tags: python, list, punctuation

I'm trying to remove a list of punctuation from my text file but I have only one problem with words separated from hyphen. For example, if I have the word "post-trauma" I get "posttrama" conversely I want to get "post" "trauma".

My code is:

```
 punct=['!', '#', '"', '%', '$', '&', ')', '(', '+', '*', '-'] 

 with open(myFile, "r") as f:
      text= f.read()
      remove = '|'.join(REMOVE_LIST) #list of word to remove
      regex = re.compile(r'('+remove+r')', flags=re.IGNORECASE) 
      out = regex.sub("", text)

      delta= " ".join(out.split())
      txt = "".join(c for c in delta if c not in punct )
```

Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: you should use a regex, where you don't want [a-zA-Z].*-[a-z] to be removed

Comment: Just tossing this out, have you tried out = regex.sub(" ",text)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can just call the built-in `replace` function on delta, so your last line would become the following:

```
txt = "".join(c for c in delta.replace("-", " ") if c not in punct )
```

This means all the hyphens in your text will become spaces, so the words will be treated as if they were separate.

Answer (score 0):

The above method might not work as you still remove all the dash ("-") characters from the inital string. If you want it to work, remove it from the list punct. The updated code looks like this:

```
punct=['!', '#', '"', '%', '$', '&', ')', '(', '+', '*'] 

 with open(myFile, "r") as f:
      text= f.read()
      remove = '|'.join(REMOVE_LIST) #list of word to remove
      regex = re.compile(r'('+remove+r')', flags=re.IGNORECASE) 
      out = regex.sub("", text)

      delta= " ".join(out.split())
      txt = "".join(c for c in delta.replace("-", " ") if c not in punct )
```

The problem comes from the fact that you are replacing all the characters in punct with an empty string, and you want a space for the "-". Thus, you need to replace the characters twice (once with empty string, and once with a space).