# how to remove all punctuation and other symbols from text document in python?

Tags: python-3.x, symbols, data-cleaning

i want to clean data set for classification. I want to remove all the useless symbols from the text.

how to remove all these useless symbols so that the text is ready for tokenisation and splitting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python remove punctuation from a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225435/python-remove-punctuation-from-a-text-file)

Comment: And possible duplicate of *many* questions about removing specific symbols from strings in python. Please take the time to search for your question before asking a new one. If you believe your question is not a duplicate, please specify what is different about your case that makes it so that the existing questions do not resolve it :)

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can  remove one character from a string:

```
x = "abcdef"
x = x.replace("a", "")
print(x)
#output: "bcdef"
```

If you want to remove multiple characters you can make use the replace function multiple times with alwas another character or you can do:

```
x = "abcdef"
to_remove = "be"
for i in to_remove:
    x = x.replace(i, "")
print(x)
#output: "acdf"
```